# Get first element from the selected group

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this `$("div.modal-window.modal-progress a")` selection I get two elements:

[image]

How to get the first  selected object from the group and display it own property?

I tried this `console.log($("div.modal-window.modal-progress a")[0].baseURI)` but I get undefined.

Each of the selected in the set has baseURI:

[image]

And how one is able to iterate over all in the set?

Comment: Does `$("div.modal-window.modal-progress a")[0]` exist and have `baseURI` key?

Comment: Yes, see the update

Comment: @Hairi: There you go - $("div.modal-window.modal-progress a").each(function(){console.log(this, $(this))})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("div.modal-window.modal-progress a")[0]` should get you the first item.

You get an undefined result because the property `baseURI` might not be defined in the first element.

If you want to get a jQuery object from the first selection, you can wrap the selected element by a `$` like this:

`$($("div.modal-window.modal-progress a")[0])`

*EDIT:* After the OP changed his question:

You might want to use [jQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over all the elements that match your selector.

```
$("div.modal-window.modal-progress a").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).prop("baseURI"));
});
```

Comment: In this case I get the html element, not an object

Comment: Your question says `How to get the first selected object from the group and display it own property?` and not how to iterate them?

Comment: @Ankit Agarwal: Well I assume he/she was asking for the first jQuery-Object and not the first DOM-Object. So the comment here might be correct :-)

Comment: @Lain It's not clearly mentioned in the question if he wants a jQuery object, so clearly that comment is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div.modal-window.modal-progress a:first")
```

might just do it. Do post more of your code though so we can see the structure.

Comment: How to get the seccond then?

Comment: @Hairi that's not what your question asked. If you have additional queries, either research for yourself or ask a new question. I'd suggest doing some research yourself as that is a common request which has been asked and answered a lot

Comment: @Tomas Edwards
Yes you answered my qeustion and I will select your answer as accepted. But if you know how to iterate please tell me or send a link.

Comment: I think @nashcheez’s answer might be more what you’re after.

Answer (score 2):

Use **first()** function of JQuery as

```
$("div.modal-window.modal-progress a").first()
```

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .first() method constructs a new jQuery object from the first element in that set.

Comment: But what If I want to iterate them?

Comment: @Hairi: With each https://api.jquery.com/each/. You should not ask for first and then suddenly ask for something else, really.

Comment: Your question specifically states you only want the first one...?

Comment: @Lain correct he asks for `How to get the first selected object from the group and display it own property?` and not how to iterate them?

Comment: @Ankit Agarwal: Aint me.